# Difference between my droplet's postgres database and a newly created managed database

Tags: django, database, postgresql, digital-ocean, django-database

What's the difference between my droplet's postgres database and a newly created managed database?

I currently have a running web app that I made via django that's hosted on digital-ocean cloud service. My project involves sending of temperature data from an IoT micro-controller via wifi to a temporary 'free' phpmyadmin database and I pull the data with the 'urllib' command in my python script.

Obviously, this process is unnecessarily long and sometimes takes my website lengthy time to load (sometimes I get a 502 Gateway Error).

I will like my ESP32 sensors to send data directly to a database on the same digital-ocean server. Is the "managed database cluster" what I need or I can still send the data to the current postgres database I had setup during the initial droplet creation process?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use your own DB rather than the managed service. The managed service is for bigger deployments where you need the data spread about etc.The managed service also costs *extra* whereas your own db is free (besides the droplet cost)

Comment: Thank you. Does that mean that there are GUI ways I can access my schemas in the database?

Comment: No. it's an empty database till you do something with it. You could install something like [PGAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/)